# Is there any way to resolve play 2.3.0 configuration error?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I am trying to run **activator clean compile** command to setup play framework project on my local machine,but it gives me **Https required error** .I am new to play framework so please help  me if anyone knows how to resolve it.I am attaching error screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was the version of sbt I was running (0.13.0) which contained the problematic `http` maven repository reference.

Try changing the following line in your build.properties:

```
sbt.version=0.13.18
```

If you're just starting out, I'd also recommend starting on a later version of Play Framework.  The current stable version is 2.8.0 (https://www.playframework.com/getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to run **activator clean compile** command to setup play framework project on my local machine

I [EOLed](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/introducing-a-new-way-to-get-started-with-lightbend-technologies-and-saying-goodbye-to-activator) Activator in 2017. Please use the latest distribution of [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) instead.

For batch execution of `clean` and `compile`, `sbt` (shell script + launcher) should be a drop-in replacement of Activator.

Activator's only interesting feature, templating, is now subsumed by superior [Giter8](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/) integration via `sbt new` command.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the maven.org repository is no longer accepting http requests (as of 15th Jan) and unfortunately play 2.3.0 is configured to use http.

The solution would be to replace the http call with a https variant, but I have no idea where that call is or how to change it.  I've also tried adding resolvers in the build.sbt but the system seems to continue using the original http call :(

I'll report back if I find anything.